# Terraform set variable with default value if empty

Tags: terraform

Hello i have problem with:

```
   on ../terraform-modules/terraform-employee/main.tf line 146, in module "ac-vm":
│  146:     token_user            = module.ac-gitlab[0].token
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.ac-gitlab is empty tuple
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: the collection has no elements.
```

```
  gitlab = {
   token_user            = module.ac-gitlab[0].token

  }
```

The problem is when it's empty. It is empty because it was not created for him on purpose.

it tries to do if null then some other default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

```
token_user = length(module.ac-gitlab) > 0 ? module.ac-gitlab[0].token : ""
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).